# how to capture VoIP phone traffic on my computer using Wireshark?

Tags: voip, wireshark, arp

I have done a few captures with wireshark on my computer, and I see ARP messages, which are think they are coming form the the VoIP phone, which is connected to the computer(USB cable). I think they should not be there, but I wonder how I can capture and indentify VoIP traffic in my computer.

I have typed the following filters but I see  none:

```
sip.CSeq.method eq INVITE


sip.Request-Line contains INVITE
```

Comment: If this device is connected with USB it's most likely "VoIP phone" consisting of sound card and HID keypad, not actual VoIP endpoint. Are you actually using SIP or rather e.g. Skype? Just "sip" as filter would be enough.

Comment: Yes, it is using the Skype for business version on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture the traffic from the USB. See https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB how to setup such a capture.